# Пример применения паттерна "Фабричный метод". В чём преимущество?

Tags: php, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, рефакторинг, factory

Здесь приведён пример из реальной жизни:
https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/factory-method/php/example#example-1

У меня два вопроса касательно этого примера:

1. В чём преимущетсва данных классов-фабрик? Абстрагировать клиентский код от конкретных классов? Но ведь можно это сделать и без фабрик вовсе. Я переписал данный пример без фабрик и привязки к конкретному классу-коннектору: https://pastebin.com/c6bEHbYw
2. Почему в классе SocialNetworkPoster присутствует метод post, который не относится к его обязанности? Не нарушает ли это SRP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1 Вопрос

### UPD. Это шаблон Фабрика

Не всегда мы знаем, экземпляр какого именно класса нужно создать. Например, я захотел написать [HTTP клиент по PSR](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-18/):

```php
namespace Psr\Http\Client;

use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

interface ClientInterface
{
    /**
     * Sends a PSR-7 request and returns a PSR-7 response.
     *
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     *
     * @return ResponseInterface
     *
     * @throws \Psr\Http\Client\ClientExceptionInterface If an error happens while processing the request.
     */
    public function sendRequest(RequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface;
}
```

При этом я не хочу обременять пользователей какой-то конкретной реализацией [PSR-7](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/)

Тогда я в конструкторе своего клиента буду получать фабрику ответа (фабрики HTTP-сообщений, кстати, тоже есть в PSR, это [PSR-17](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-17/)).

```php
namespace Some\Namespace;


use Psr\Http\Client\ClientInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseFactoryInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

class HttpClient implements ClientInterface
{

    /**
     * @var ResponseFactoryInterface
     */
    private $responseFactory;

    public function __construct(ResponseFactoryInterface $responseFactory)
    {
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    }    

    public function sendRequest(RequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface
    {
        // ...
        // посылаю запрос, получаю сырой ответ
        // ...
        $response = $this->responseFactory
            ->createResponse($status, $phrase)
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', $contentType)
        ;
        $response->getBody()->write($contents);
        $response->getBody()->rewind();
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Теперь пользователь моей библиотеки точно знает, какого класса будет ответ.

### Шаблон фабричный метод

Иногда в конструкторе класса можно передать параметры, значения которых зависят друг от друга и программист может допустить ошибку.

```php
class Address
{
    public function __construct($street, $build, $letter, $apartment)
    {
    }
}
```

По адресу может быть частный дом и там квартира не нужна.

Можно запретить явно вызывать конструктор и сделать фабричные методы

```php
class Address
{
    private function __construct($street, $build, $letter, $apartment)
    {
    }

    public static function createApartment($street, $build, $letter, $apartment)
    {
        return new self($street, $build, $letter, $apartment);
    }

    public static function createHome($street, $build, $letter)
    {
        return new self($street, $build, $letter, null);
    }
}
```

Теперь программист не ошибется.

## 2 Вопрос.

Возможно, данный пример и нарушает SRP, но в целом пример остается корректным, т.к. не имеет отношения к принципу единой ответственности.

Comment: Этот пример куда понятнее! Кажется я понял.
Фабрика нужна в том случае, когда пользователь класса не должен создавать объект, реализующий некий интерфейс.

Т.е. в данном примере, нет смысла указывать в сигнатуре конструктора `ResponseInterface`, т.к. не пользователь данного класса должен создавать этот объект, а сам класс (HttpClient)

Я правильно понял? В этом и цель данного паттерна?

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли

Comment: Прошу прощения, я был сонный и не совсем правильно ответил. Я ответил по шаблону `Фабрика`, а не `Фабричный метод`. Фабричный метод - это немного другое...

Comment: Я добавил в ответ про фабричный метод

Comment: Мне кажется, всё с точностью до наоброт :)
2-й пример с адресом это как раз простая фабрика и шаблоном как таковым не является.